# Exclude dependency from Application Server auto deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, deployment, war, jboss7.x

I've got EJB object which requires some interfaces from dependency (maven - jar). When I deploy it in .ejb in .ear everything works. I really don't need ear so I wanted to use .war with this EJB object. However during deployment it appeared that my dependency has some classes annotated with @Webservice. This classes also requires other dependencies which I don't want to use in my project, so during deployment I get no class def found exception. Is there any way to stop this auto-deployment of annotated classes from dependency?

Comment: Do you need to exclude just those classes from the dependency, or the entire dependency itself?

Comment: It would be perfect if simply AS wont deploy these classes as webservices etc, but they would be still included in build. Effect similiar to disabling whole webservice submodule in jboss.

Comment: Have you tried removing the web services extension? e.g. just comment out the `<extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>`.

Comment: Removing web services extension works, but I'm wondering is it possible to disable not for all classes in case I might have my own webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) `filters` and/or `minimizeJar` features to exclude classes from that dependency.