# How can I avoid EJB annotation scanning in dependency JARs packaged in a WAR?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I'm building a WAR project with some `@Stateless` session beans included (located in `WEB-INF/classes`). During deployment, classpath scanning kicks in, and my beans get deployed and registered in JNDI, all fine.

Now I need to include a dependency `foo-service.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib` which contains the remote interface and implementation(!) of some EJBs with `@Stateful` and `@Stateless` annotations that I need to call remotely from my WAR application. Now these beans get deployed, too, which seems to be fine as per the [specification of EJBs packaged in WARs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipio.html).

However, I do not want these beans to be deployed, as I want to *consume* the implementation of the remote interface, not provide it.

Q: Is there some standard mechanism to suppress EJB annotation scanning for selected JARs in a WAR? "Hey, JBoss, do not scan that JAR!"

---

Approaches I considered so far:

- I might repackage the external dependency so that I get a JAR which contains only the interfaces, not the implementations. (This is suggested in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367225/exclude-dependency-from-application-server-auto-deployment)) Touching the JAR feels cumbersome, and I'd like to avoid it.
- Requesting the developers to split interfaces and implementation into separate JARs would take too much time until they get it released.
- I might put an `ejb-jar.xml` into `WEB-INF` that contains only my "own" beans, not those from `foo-service.jar`. I guess this will work (haven't tried it yet), but it would suddenly force me to define *all* my beans explicitly, giving up the benefits of annotation scanning entirely.
- I might wrap everything in an EAR and not mention `foo-service.jar` in `application.xml`. Not exactly complexity-reducing, and it feels like to much for my tiny web application...

Comment: Hi steffen, which tool are you using to build the war? Would the maven dependency scope be a help?

Comment: @Tim, I'm using Maven for building the WAR project. I don't get your idea yet, how would the scope help me. Either I have the JAR packaged into the WAR or not. And I need the JAR packaged (scope is 'compile'), as I need the interface class-file during runtime.

Comment: @TimLong, sorry for the late reply - I was unfamiliar with the SO Markup syntax for user mentions. Please see my previous comment for the actual reply. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but maybe you can add your `foo-service.jar` as a module in jboss. Then in your web app you can reference to that module in `WEB-INF\jboss-deployment-structure.xml` ( or in Dependency entry in MANIFEST.MF).
See [here](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1933) or [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7)

Comment: Did you make up `foo-service.jar`?

Comment: "I might repackage the external dependency so that I get a JAR which contains only the interfaces, not the implementations."
That means that `foo-service.jar` is external

Comment: Oh wait, I didn't read the question properly. ```I need to include a dependency `foo-service.jar` ```

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. I will have to consider again whether I want to put application code into a module, hence scattering the deployment other several places. But your idea definitely points into a good direction.